# Async update of UI

Tags: c#, winforms

I have datagridview and need to update it on separate thread. Or maybe even on same thread but only when data ready. I have 90% of data loading right away and would like to show it to user. Then I have 2 more columns that can load 20+ seconds sometimes and would like to update them as soon as data ready. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: backgroundworker: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Comment: [Async IO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw97wx20.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WinForms, your best bet is [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx), it's a nice class for doing work on a different thread and updating a WinForms based UI.

Comment: Please check comments, it's repeat.

Comment: That doesn't mean @Matt deserves to lose credit. Does it? People are ungrateful enough as is.

Comment: @Sanjeevakumar Please check timestamps, the comment and my answer were posted at the same time.

Comment: @Sanjeevakumar even they posted at different times, doesn't matter. This answer pointed me to what I need. And, this is only answer I can MARK as answer since others are comments.

Answer (score 0):

Having not seen any code, I would suggest creating your own event. Once the data is ready, you throw a new event with the new data as the argument, and then load that. It'll happen on the same UI thread though.

Not sure if you already have a way to poll for that being completed. Making a thread to run in the background and just poll for that wouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the remaining 10% of your data coming from?  What are you binding to?  Is this a scenario where you're making one hit to your data source for the "90%" and then making a totally separate hit to go get the rest of your data?

Comment: yes, exactly. 90% of data comes in as 1 load. And then remaining 10% get's loaded row by row..